# Continuous collision detection(CCD) in flame and/or forge2d

Tags: flame, forge2d

Still new to game engines and Flame.

I have some tunneling/ghost collision detection using Flame. I found that you should use continuous collision detection(CCD).

I don't see any CCD in Flame or forge2d, what do you do to handel tunneling?

Answer (score 1):

Forge2D has CCD if you set the body to be a bullet with either `body.setBullet(true);` or `bodyDef.bullet = true`.

Have you tried the new collision detection system in `1.1.0-releasecandidate.5`? It still doesn't do CCD, but it is a bit better than the one in `1.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am on "1.1.0-releasecandidate.5". I will try out Forge2D body.